# Dropwizard UriInfo contain invalid baseUri

Tags: dropwizard

I've faced a problem when I get base URI form uriInfo. Here's a part of code:

```
@Path("/users")
@POST
public Response createUser(@RequestBody User user, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    ...
    String confirmEmailUrl = uriInfo.getBaseUri().resolve("/users/confirm/" + getConfirmEmailLink(user));
    ...
}
```

confirmEmailUrl must be like `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/users/confirm/aergserthserg` but I get the following result `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/users/confirm/aergserthserg`. The problem within the port. I used in some other methods `uriInfo` to build the URL and it works correctly. What is wrong here?

Comment: Which UrIInfo package are you using? And version?

Comment: UriInfo is from com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.1